# Elastic Search : Search keyword results of a specific category

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a query where I'm trying to search for names of people of a specific country. If I provide input as `John` and `USA`, I should only find results of people by the name `John` (by the property : name) from USA (by the property : country) and results from other countries shouldn't appear in the results.

What I have tried :

```
 "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "John",
                        "fields": ["username", "first_name", "last_name"],
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                        "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "is_citizen": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

With the above query the problem I'm seeing is that the results also show people **who don't have their name as `John` but are from USA
**.

```
Expectation : To filter results of given keyword specific to given country.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `should` you need to use `must` clause in your name query.

Below query should give you expected results. refer [boolean query official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to understand the difference with examples.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ --> note `must` here
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "John",
                        "fields": ["username", "first_name", "last_name"],
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                        "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "is_citizen": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the above query is that if I search for `Jo` (while typing John), I don't get any results. Only when I type in John - I'm getting results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using should clause thats why it is not working. You can use `must` insted of `should` and it will resolved your issue.

You can use `"type":"phrase_prefix"` to match `Jo` with `John`.

You can change your query as shown below and it will work:

```json
 "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "John",
                        "fields": ["username", "first_name", "last_name"],
                        "type":"phrase_prefix",
                        "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "is_citizen": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the above query is that if I search for Jo (while typing John), I don't get any results. Only when I type in John - I'm getting results.

Comment: @WAS I have updated the question and addded `type` param which will solve your issue.